# Testing Zustand state change caused by a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, vitest, zustand

I have a react custom hook which uses React Query to fetch data. While doing that Zustand state get updates for loading states and with response data.
I want to test the zustand state changes on the custom hook but can't import the state into the test suites.

Custom hook

```
export const useLogIn = () => {
 const setAuthLoading = useCombinedStore((state) => state.setAuthLoading);
 const setAuthData = useCombinedStore((state) => state.setAuthData);

 const { mutate } = useMutation({
  mutationFn: (inputData) => {
   setAuthLoading(true);
   return fetch(...);
  },
  onSuccess: async (data) => {
   setAuthData(data);
   setAuthLoading(false);
  },
  onError: ...
 });
 return mutate;
};
```

Zustand combine store

```
const useCombineStore = create((...a) => ({
 ...createAuthSlice(...a),
 ...otherStores(...a),
}));

export default useCombinedStore;
```

Auth store

```
const createAuthSlice = (set) => ({
 authData: null,
 isAuthLoading: false,
 setAuthData: (authData) => set(() => ({ authData })),
 setAuthLoading: (isAuthLoading) => set(() => ({ isAuthLoading })),
});

export default createAuthSlice;
```

Test suites using Vitest

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
import { describe, it, vi } from 'vitest';
import { useLogIn } from '../../src/hooks/auth';
import wrapper from '../wrapperMaker';
import useCombinedStore from '../../src/store/CombineStore';

describe('#useLogIn', () => {
  it('should login a user successfully', async () => {
    const { result: stateResult } = renderHook(() =>
      useCombinedStore((state) => {
        return state.isAuthLoading
      })
    );
    console.log(stateResult.current.getState());
    const { result: test } = renderHook(async () => useLogIn({ email, password       }), { wrapper });
  });
});
```

Always the getState is undefined. Don't know how to import state to test the changes.

Here is Zustand store mock.

```
    // __mocks__/zustand.js
    import { vi, afterEach } from 'vitest';
    import { act } from '@testing-library/react';

    const { create: actualCreate } = await vi.importActual('zustand');
    export const storeResetFns = new Set();

    export const create = () => {
      return (StateCreator) => {
        const store = actualCreate(StateCreator);
        const initialState = store.getState();
        storeResetFns.add(() => {
          store.setState(initialState, true);
        });
        return store;
      };
    };

    afterEach(() => {
      act(() => {
        storeResetFns.forEach((resetFn) => {
          resetFn();
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Since I can't see all of your code, is it possible you missed some steps for setting it up? https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/testing

The code you've shared looks correct, so I'm not sure what could be causing it.

Comment: There seems to be a thread about something similar here: https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/issues/982

Comment: @SeedyROM I've followed the documentation. It's in TS, but I've converted them to JS with exact things.
[github issue](http://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/issues/982) is about returning the state from the hook. But here in my case I only expose the React Query function

Comment: Right you probably can't mock React Query then with your current setup? I could be wrong. Since I don't have a fully reproducible I can't debug any further. I also don't see any React Query code in your examples.

Comment: @SeedyROM actually I haveused React Query in the 'wrap' on useLogin renderHook. Any suggestions that I could import the Zustand store values to the test suite?